# WordPress - Изменить URL одной страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress. В настройках Permalinks стоит опция Plain, то есть адреса страниц имеют вид https://site.com/?p=123. Но адрес одной страницы нужно изменить на слово: https://site.com/test. Весь интернет перерыл, неужели в WP такое нельзя реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать add_rewrite_rule примерно так:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^test/?', 'index.php?p=123', 'top' );
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule